# Getting data from XML and iterating through jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get multiple zip names one after another using an each loop but i'm getting is the final zip from the loop when clicking the respective class names. can anyone help me.

XML File:

```
<navigation>
    <link>
        <targetLink>.home</targetLink>
        <destination>home.zip</destination>
    </link>
    <link>
        <targetLink>.ref</targetLink>
        <destination>reference.zip</destination>
    </link>
    <link>
        <targetLink>.sumarry</targetLink>
        <destination>symarry.zip</destination>
    </link>
</navigation>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ajax call</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sumarry">Left Menu1</div>
    <div class="ref">Left Menu2</div>
    <div class="home">Left Menu3</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Java Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var targetLink="";
    var destination="";
       $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "navigation.xml",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(data) {
                 $(data).find('link').each(function(){
                    var targetLink = $(this).find("targetLink").text()
                    destination = $(this).find('destination').text();
                    $(document).on("click", targetLink, function() {
                        document.location = veeva:gotoslide(destination);
                    })
                });
                }

        });
});
```

I am getting the class names but when i am clicking the respective class names it takes me to the last zip file. can any one help me how i will get the respective destination zip file for each class name.

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: .find("targetLink").text() ... you get name of class but you need add dot for defined class .... like a  '.' + targetLink

Comment: you can try get destination in .on(click function via $(this)

Comment: In my XML, I am passing my class name as (".home").

Comment: if i will write $(this) inside $(document).on("click", targetLink, function(){}) then "$(this)" will take the current scope i.e $(document) and i will not get the destination.

Comment: and why you use .on in success? If you use .on it will listen always on document. Iam not sure if is good way to use .on in succes and each fnc because you don't click on xml but html

Comment: If i am writing like $(targetLink).bind("click", function() { document.location = veeva:gotoslide(destination);}). then also i am getting the last zip file.

Comment: its because you handle class name but you need to know where you are clicking, its $(this) where you are and you can find in xml correct destination